# Angular 9 sharing between feature modules?

Tags: angular

Angular advises structural guidelines (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules) and "Rule of One" (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#rule-of-one) as follows:

[image: Overall structural guidelines]

So: if I have a **Dashboard feature that needs to display some summary Hero information**, should I move the hero service and model out of the heroes feature module and into /app/shared so that both the Heroes module and Dashboard module can access them? Or, should the Dashboard module import from the Heroes module?

To my understanding, feature modules are supposed to be self-contained, and shouldn't import models etc from anywhere...

Comment: Do you want the logical app structure physically structured as well?

Comment: Yes--I'm physically structuring via feature modules.

Comment: That sounds like a solid starting point. Will you take some time and explore letting those structures be more loosely coupled?  to this statement you had made "To my understanding, feature modules are supposed to be self-contained, and shouldn't import models etc from anywhere..."  take everything architectural with a grain of salt. These rules are meant to be a guideline, not a matter of fact! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be viewed at different angles.

If you are asking about a pure-angular architecture approach/solution, then my answer would be - yes, create a Dashboard module and import Heroes module into it. Dashboards in particular have natural tendency to adopt more and more data as they grow, very likely from yet different modules, not only Heroes. So this would be a scalable solution.

However there is another approach...

Whenever the concept of sharing data among modules arises, it is very legit to start thinking of using some kind of state management (such as ngrx.io). The main purpose of having an app-level state is to be able to share data and have a centralized, single source of truth. You would benefit a lot when your app grows app. It is scalable and doesn't require architectural changes just for the sake of being able to interchange data.

For the purpose of having a dashboard I can hardly imagine a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I have used redux before (in the context of React); but, wouldn't this require the Heroes feature module (and others) to 'know about' the central, app-level state store?

Comment: Not sure about others, but as far as ngrx goes, nope - a feature module doesn't need to know anything about the shell app. Dashboard container/facade will use the selectors of the modules whose data will be displayed, such as Heros. The decisions that need to be made though would include preserving the lazy loading of the feature modules.

Comment: I can answer the question with an example.  @user776686 is this sort of what you are referring too? the examples a little sloppy.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/os-5096-documents-review-component-and-document-list-com-chqxts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdocuments-api.service.ts

Comment: @user776686 exactly - in my case the 'heroes' module is to be lazy-loaded. . .so I suppose if Dashboard imports Heroes module, then lazy-load is kind of out the door (since dashboard is first point of navigation following login).

Comment: @user2132190 I just wrote that the other day. so if you have questions ask. it's pretty fresh on my mind.